# Who was the old lady in the woods?

Tags: plot-explanation, i-dont-feel-at-home-in-this-world

In the movie *I Don't Feel at Home in this World Anymore*, When Ruth is at the woods looking for Tony, she sees an old lady in red with a cigar and (I think) a glass of alcohol in her hands. Who is she?

I believe she is Ruth as a ghost (even though she is alive) because of the cigar, the alcohol and she looks happy -  throughout the movie we see Ruth's concern about the afterlife. But I am not sure.

Comment: I haven't seen the film, but perhaps the script might help; https://assets.scriptslug.com/live/pdf/scripts/i-dont-feel-at-home-in-this-world-anymore-2017.pdf